# How to send data between HTTP requests without user modifying it?

Tags: web-applications, security

I'm currently developing a web application (using laravel) where I have a form that edit a resource. Something like this:

```
<!-- URL: /editResource/3 -->
<form action="/editResource/3" method="POST">
     <!-- Input fields -->
</form>
```

When I send the form the web application will update the resource 3.

But how I can prevent something like using developer tools to modify /editResource/3 to /editResource/4 and edit the wrong resource?

I'm not asking how to prevent some user editing other user resources; this can be accomplished by a simple validation, but I'm asking how to prevent user modifying this kind of data, since HTTP is stateless.

Thank you

EDIT: The question was misleading, I want to clarify that what I'm trying to find is a way to keep some information between requests, without user modifying it. I'm sending the information: ***3*** to the client so in the next request, the server knows that the user is editing the resource 3, but I want to do this without the risk generated by user changing this data.

Comment: Assuming the user is authorized resource 4, you can't.

Comment: What is the risk? You can validate it server-side, and no user is going to *accidentally* change the resource

Comment: You might be able to use a MAC, but that's still potentially vulnerable to replay attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd store the data server side in a session object or user profile record and then send the unmodified data each time.

Answer (score 7):

You can't.  If the data is on the user's end, the user is in control of it, not you.  Trying to change this is an arms race you don't want to get into.

Instead, worry about what you have control of: the server.  Validate data instead of blindly trusting it.  HTTP may be stateless, but your app on the server-side doesn't have to be!

Comment: I edited the question, I'm asking something different, I need to send the data between requests, but without user modifying it.

Comment: @IAmJulianAcosta I would contend that the answer is still the same.  You can't. When its on the client end, the client can modify it and trying to prevent that is an arms race.

Comment: You can validate that the user hasn't modified the data by sending a cryptograhic hash of the data to the user along with the data.  The user then returns the data and the hash.  The user cannot modify the data without the server detecting it.

Comment: @IAmJulianAcosta: The best you can do is to generate non-sequential ID's, so that it becomes that much harder for a user to change it to a different valid one.

Comment: @CraigAnderson: That makes no sense to do. The server doesn't have to accept data the client sends if it doesn't want to. If you don't want the client to change data, just ignore whatever the client says!

Comment: @whatsisname Let me give a concrete example. The web server sends the client some cookies.  The client sends some cookies back.  If you generate a hash of the cookies, the server can detect if the client changed the cookies.

Comment: @CraigAnderson: if you want to detect if the client is sending bogus cookies, you don't need to both hashing, just do a plain-jane comparion.

Comment: @whatsisname- yes, the server could store the cookies and check that they match.  Using a hash means that the server doesn't need to store the cookies.

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson but it does need to store the hash

Comment: @user253751 - the server can either store the hash, or it can encrypt it, which means the client can't generate a new hash for the tampered cookies.